# Azure Notification Service: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ExpiredToken: .TrackingId:

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

I am making use of Azure Notification Service.

I log the result of every push notification that I send to azure.

I sometimes get the following Result / Response:

> "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
>   ExpiredToken:
>   .TrackingId:f38f2e96-23b9-4c5b-880g-1358c5c15316_G4,TimeStamp:9/1/2016
>   9:48:14 PM"

I get like 2 - 10 in a row in the space of 1 second. And then it starts working again.

here is my log:

```
Date    Result
2016-09-01 22:07:02.81  Enqueued
2016-09-01 22:07:02.67  Enqueued
2016-09-01 22:05:34.03  The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ExpiredToken: .TrackingId:9bf11f89-9c54-4213-8e42
2016-09-01 22:04:44.52  The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ExpiredToken: .TrackingId:36fb0e8b-7d0f-4145-a125
2016-09-01 22:04:44.51  The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ExpiredToken: .TrackingId:23c76f68-52ca-404a-ad31
2016-09-01 22:04:44.09  The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ExpiredToken: .TrackingId:ceb11915-745a-4924-80cf
2016-09-01 22:04:44.09  The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ExpiredToken: .TrackingId:75c61cba-fadc-4c05-8fe2
2016-09-01 22:03:52.82  The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ExpiredToken: .TrackingId:e3696e3d-a44b-4179-a14a
2016-09-01 22:03:52.82  The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ExpiredToken: .TrackingId:ea3c040b-e358-461b-a56f
2016-09-01 22:03:52.40  The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ExpiredToken: .TrackingId:2eb9901d-e267-4053-a6a4
2016-09-01 22:03:52.40  The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ExpiredToken: .TrackingId:163730b1-b7ef-43e8-adaf
2016-09-01 22:03:51.98  The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ExpiredToken: .TrackingId:f28412c5-262f-4891-b991
2016-09-01 22:03:51.55  The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ExpiredToken: .TrackingId:48b5dc83-ee3a-4d3f-b525
2016-09-01 22:03:51.55  The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ExpiredToken: .TrackingId:a64ce0b1-dd6d-4972-8990
2016-09-01 22:03:51.13  The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ExpiredToken: .TrackingId:b43bde8d-febb-4624-99c6
2016-09-01 22:03:51.13  The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ExpiredToken: .TrackingId:17bd762d-0b4b-450c-bf09
2016-09-01 22:03:50.71  The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ExpiredToken: .TrackingId:9abef735-bf42-4494-9721
2016-09-01 22:03:50.71  The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ExpiredToken: .TrackingId:3f9b9c82-e37e-48c4-931e
2016-09-01 22:03:50.29  The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ExpiredToken: .TrackingId:685a2286-6f0b-4fdf-9dd6
2016-09-01 22:03:50.28  The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ExpiredToken: .TrackingId:3715eee2-b4b6-4ec4-9141
2016-09-01 22:03:49.87  The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ExpiredToken: .TrackingId:91212080-719f-4b95-b9da
2016-09-01 22:03:49.86  The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ExpiredToken: .TrackingId:bd1f5ae4-1a38-40d6-87ba
2016-09-01 22:03:48.01  The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ExpiredToken: .TrackingId:47307851-cd9b-4632-94b6
2016-09-01 22:03:22.07  The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ExpiredToken: .TrackingId:c8a21d16-de82-4fef-b2e
2016-09-01 22:03:22.07  The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ExpiredToken: .TrackingId:1fe9246d-19fc-4818-b8a8
2016-09-01 22:03:11.44  Enqueued
2016-09-01 22:03:11.34  Enqueued
```

What could this error message mean?

[After some thinking]

Could this be a threading issue? The way I implemented this code is that there is a singleton instance of `NotificationHubClient` which each task gets and then calls `SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync()`.

Comment: Could [clock synchronization](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bbe5699a-763c-445e-b174-86a55e460c05/notification-hubs-call-registernativeasync-returns-registrationauthorizationexception-401?forum=notificationhubs) be a problem? If the post doesn't help, could you share your namespace name?

Comment: I have no Idea? I did notice that in the 401 there was a time-stamp field and I did notice that it was about 5 minutes ahead of my time-stamp.

Comment: Is this a production deployment or are you running on the emulator? If the latter, could you make sure that the clock is manually set to the correct time?

Comment: Production deployment.  When you say correct time. Is that relevant to any time zone?

Comment: Not sure if this was ultimately resolved. Regarding the last question, the time 'correctness' would be the correct time for the configured time-zone.  For example if you are in Pacific Daylight Savings, make sure the current time is correct for that timezone.  If you are in [Newfoundland Time Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newfoundland_Time_Zone), make sure the time is right for that timezone.  Correct time is essential to security checking.

Comment: Yes, it looks like a timing issue on your server. Looking at the logs, you can see that the time period during which you saw the exceptions thrown lasted for ~5 mins, which you also mentioned is about the amount of time of the lag that you observed. Could you make sure that your production server has correct time set up? Also, consider the advice by @Sateesh in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be racing issue. To workaround, could you create a new `NotificationHubClient` for every task (`NotificationHubClient` is very light weight object).

Comment: This is the approach I have moved over to for safety.

Answer (score 1):

The NotificationHub .NET SDK just fixed an issue where the SAS token was expiring on heavily used and long live connection clients. You can see the issue on GitHub here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-dotnet/commit/be52eefcd418f8e0540620a0ea64be0c9dea2488

We originally had our NotificationHubClient instance registered as a singleton and we ran into this same issue. However, once we moved over to calling NotificationHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString() for each request we ended up with port exhaustion issues that we suspect were a result of the underlying issues that arise when you create lots of HttpClients instead of reusing them. The root problem is that NotificationHubClient creates a new HttpClient instance in its constructor for the underlying communication with the NotificationHub, so in effect you end up creating a bunch of short-lived HttpClients with this approach.

Their 2.0.2 update just came out a few days ago, so if you have a high-volume scenario you should probably go back to instantiating your NotificationHubClient as a singleton once you've pulled the latest update.

Hope this helps!